# How run an shell alias docker command from Ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible

one customer has a playbook which runs local actions, in this case, a sqlplus command against RDS endpoint.

```
 shell: "echo exit|sqlplus64 '{{db_pnyx_username}}/{{db_pnyx_password}}@//{{ host }}:{{ port }}/{{db_pnyx_service_name}}' @vhosts.sql"
```

As I'm running Ubuntu I got curious how to avoid to install so many dependencies of packages due to sqlplus package so I decided to try in a container way.

```
 - name : Execute SQL 
    shell: "echo exit|docker run --rm  --net=host -v $PWD:/tmp rubendob/sqlplus:dockerplus '{{db_pnyx_username}}/{{db_pnyx_password}}@//{{ host }}:{{ port }}/{{db_pnyx_service_name}}' @/tmp/vhosts.sql"
    register: result
```

And it worked!

but I also wanted to run the docker with the alias shortcut from my .profile file as it is shown below:

```
alias sqlplus64='docker run --rm --net=host -v $PWD:/tmp rubendob/sqlplus:dockerplus'
```

Ansible always returns an error:

```
"stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: sqlplus64: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: sqlplus64: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Is there any way to achieve this according to best practices? I bet I'm doing lot of bad stuff here :(

Comment: Your question seems to contain a solution. What is the problem to solve?

Comment: Don't contain the solution I guess. The problem is how to run "alias" of the local Ubuntu shell when are being called from Ansible.